# How to drag and drop using selenium in canvas and kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, kineticjs

I am using selenium web driver to test my site, the thing is I had a canvas element in which I have to drag an element which is located at (0,0) to (10,0). The main thing is in canvas no elements will have ids or class names.

I browsed online but mostly found answer like

```
    Actions builder= new Actions(driver);
    WebElement canvas = driver.findElement(By.className("kineticjs-content"));
    builder.build();
    builder.moveToElement(canvas, 0, 0)
    .clickAndHold()
    .moveByOffset(0, 20)
    .release();
    builder.perform();
```

So here the main problem is we don't have and ids or class names for the elements inside canvas. So can anyone help me out to drag and drop a particular element using its (x,y) coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following for drag and drop on the canvas. In fact its a zooming on the canvas & it works for me

```
Actions slide = new Actions(driver);
WebElement text=obj.findElementByXpath(".//[@id='chartContainer']/div/canvas[2]");
        slide.build();
        text.click();
        slide.dragAndDropBy(text, 100, 4500);
        slide.perform();
        slide.release();
        }
```